# The hyperlink color seems to be difficult to distinguish from the text

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks

In my opinion (or my eyes are so bad), I think the hyperlink color is difficult to differentiate from the text. As a result, I always add a word "click" in the hyperlink to overcome this issue.

It will be better if the hyperlink color is a bit contrast to the text.

### Edit

One example is taken from [my previous comment (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194995/simple-if-statement-latex/194999#comment451032_194999).

[image]

Comment: a link to just one word, especially a short one like "here", isn't really easy to detect.  longer strings are better, so rephrasing helps.  (the problem isn't limited to this site by any means!)